# Using htaccess to remove codeigniter index.php in a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, subdirectory

I'm trying to remove the index.php from my CI urls, but having followed the instructions it doesn't seem to be working.

I have a codeigniter installation running in a subdirectory. There is a default controller set in the routes config called main, and another controller called 'create'. The default runs fine, but going to /create returns a 324 error saying No Data Received. My htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: An output of your apache error.log would be helpful to solve your problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: And the winner is ... this.

Comment: and dont forget to change the apache configuration as mentioned in stackoverflow.com/a/14807463/1537413

Answer (score 8):

This is what I use. My CodeIgniter also runs in a subdir.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|swf|uploads|js|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've been looking for the right mod_rewrite for hours and this is the one that finally worked for me! All I had to do was change `ci/` to `mysubfolder/`

Answer (score 6):

.htaccess add:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Go into application/config/config.php and clear the index page config value:

```
// Old

$config['index_page'] = "index.php";

// New

$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Solved My problem hope others too... :)

Comment: i trying the code from codeigniter user guide and didn't work but now its work like a magic thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to enable it the rewrite module, run "apache2 enable module rewrite":

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

You need to restart the webserver to apply the changes:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then folow Sofia's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

for ubuntu