# What happens when a user types only the domain name and or port number in the browser's address bar when accessing a site built with codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I know that in Codeigniter, the default controller is always called if a controller is not specified in the url. Furthermore, if a function is not specified in the url, the index function of the controller will be called by default. However when I enter the following urls in the browser address bar I get different results for each:

```
http://localhost/appfolder/
```

And

```
http://localhost/appfolder/index.php/defaultController
```

For the first url, it seems that the user is not logged in even if indeed the user is logged in. The second url works fine and does the correct thing whether the user is logged in or not, that is, it excecutes the index function of the default controller. It seems to me that the first url doesn't excecute the index function of the default controller. I'm racking my brain trying to figure out why entering the two urls produces different results because according to what I know, they're supposed to have the same results; i.e they're both supposed to call the index function of the default controller.
I'm sort of a newbie in using codeigniter (have used it for about 2 and half months now) so any help would really be appreciated.

**This is an edit:**
I know most of the comments here are about using a htaccess file but isn't it supposed to work the same way whether index.php is in the url or not? Does anyone have any other suggestions on what I can do to pinpoint the problem?

Comment: did us set default controller in your application............

Comment: Yes I did, just as has been mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: What does your htaccess look like? Because your app runs in a subfolder, it may be causing problems.

Comment: @Jeemusu I'm currently not using any htaccess file.

Comment: You need to be using one if you want to be able to access the site without the index.php in the URL. Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765883/using-htaccess-to-remove-codeigniter-index-php-in-a-subdirectory

Comment: @Jeemusu Will I need to restart apache for the htaccess file to work?

Comment: No, not at all, should work straight away. Check my answer for another link to a similar question with a bunch of useful answers.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this @ninjacoder?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the site through the url `http://localhost/appfolder` instead of `http://localhost/appfolder/index.php/defaultController` you will need to set up a .htaccess file in your sites webroot folder (the folder containing index.php). This is pretty much what I use on my site (customized for your setup):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /appfolder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

**Alternative**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /appfolder

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Similar question with plenty of discussion and other methods:
[How to remove "index.php" in codeigniter's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445385/how-to-remove-index-php-in-codeigniters-path)

Comment: I've used this example but the server throws a 404 error when I remove index.php from the url

Comment: you may also need to change the config.php so that `$config['index_page'] = '';` instead of `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`.

Comment: Try the alternative .htaccess above.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default controller in the routes config file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Blog';
```

From the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#default):

> CodeIgniter can be told to load a default controller when a URI is not present, as will be the case when only your site root URL is requested. To specify a default controller, open your application/config/routes.php file and set this variable.

Answer (score 0):

Hey use this one in your htaccess file i think it will work............

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: did u set all the base url, default controller etc settings in your config directory